# call a page within subdomain using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need to read a page content on my sub-domain using ajax get.
I thought of creating some script on my sub-domain and calling that script on my domain. however I don't know how to do it.

Is it possible to do such a thing? how?

EDIT:

I created a page in my domain that uses DownloadString and downloads that page and write down the result. any better ideas?

Comment: whats hapening now?  browsers block cros-domain ajax unless you use jsonp, but calling to subdomain should not be blocked

Comment: calling to subdomain is also blocked. I can do anything on my subdomain but don't know what to do

Comment: calling to subdomain will still be blocked, sub-domain is not same-origin. The easiest most cross-browser solution would be to use JSONP

Comment: yeah do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This post helped me before: http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#document.domain_property

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106178/get-json-from-subdomains-with-jquery

Comment: @SandeepBansal I have read about jsonp but as I understood, it doesn't work in older versions of IE

Comment: isn't it possible to write a script on subdomain and call it?

Comment: I updated my question. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to support cross-domain AJAX requests, you will need to create a cross origin resource sharing handler (CORS). I don't have an example specific to asp.net, but if you are using MVC this is fairly simply to achieve (and would be fundamentally the same for WebForms).

A Web API example may be found here to get you started:
[CorsHandler.cs](https://github.com/DavidChristiansen/DotNetOpenAuth.WebAPI.40/blob/master/source/DotNetOpenAuth.WebAPI/CorsHandler.cs)

Also, if you need to support IE 7, 8 or 9 you would want to look in to a jQuery extension lib such as [jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest)

**EDIT**

If you would like to look at a full example (again Web API unfortunately), here is a MSDN article with a full code example [Implementing CORS support in ASP.NET Web APIs](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Implementing-CORS-support-a677ab5d)

Answer (score 0):

You can also sometimes manipulate document.domain in JS. So if you're serving pages from www.site.com, and your Ajax services are hosted at app.site.com, set your document.domain to site.com.