# Chrome solution for document.domain

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cross-domain

For some reason chrome doesn't support document.domain any more and spits out an error when the line is read in the iframe containing a subdomain and the subdomain containing the iframe. Is there anyway around this?

Error: Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Document domain should be lowercase and the rules are like this:

```
// Actual domain is "www.foo.com" 
document.domain = "foo.com"; // this is valid 

// Actual domain is "bar.foo.com" 
document.domain = "www.foo.com"; // this is invalid, "bar.foo.com" is not a subdomain of "www.foo.com" 

// Actual domain is "blah.bar.foo.com" 
document.domain = "bar.foo.com" // Ok 
document.domain = "foo.com" // Still ok 
document.domain = "bar.foo.com" // Invalid, you can't change it back to a more specific domain.
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is looking for a reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

`document.domain` should work for iframes as long as you're on the same domain:

```
iframe=document.querySelector('iframe');
console.log(iframe.contentDocument.domain)
```

If you're trying to access the document of an iframe that's on a different domain than the parent frame, you'll get the security error you're seeing.

Note that subdomains are considered different domains too, so you'll run into cross domain issues: [A question about cross-domain (subdomain) ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648899/a-question-about-cross-domain-subdomain-ajax-request)