# Since when doesn't Chrome support `document.domain` setter?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-canary

Thank you in advance for reading my question.

As far as I know, `document.domain` setter in Chrome is supposed to be deprecated in M109
(The related link : https://developer.chrome.com/blog/immutable-document-domain/)

However, regarding links below, it seems like it's delayed to M110 or M111
(link 1 : https://chromestatus.com/feature/5428079583297536
link 2 : https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/nrLl0IxSxSI/m/FbWK4hIyAgAJ)

Does any one know since when Chrome doesn't support `document.domain` setter anymore?

ps. I tested `document.domain` setter in Chrome Canary which is version over M111, but it seemed still working.

Comment: In recent versions of Google Chrome, it is not possible to set the document.domain property. This has been the case since at least Chrome 73, which was released in March 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of Google Chrome, it is not possible to set the document.domain property. This has been the case since at least Chrome 73, which was released in March 2019.

Answer (score 0):

I think the true answer is much more nuanced. As long as you are [following certain rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9785085/1703887) you were able to set the document.domain property up through at least 110 (the timelines are still in flux).

Other than those rules, you have to also actually be on the same domain to set it (this feature was useful for sub domain/port issues).