# How do I retrieve and display html/asp/aspx page on different host using jQuery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, same-origin-policy

I have an html page, which is a dynamically created asp/aspx page on http://host2.mydomain.com.  **I have no control over the html page.  I cannot modify it in any such way.  I cannot modify this page; so, setting document.domain is out of the question, unfortunately.**  This html page is compiled by a 3rd-party vendor and the code is close-source; I cannot view it or change it.
 I want to retrieve and display this page on http://host1.mydomain.com/page1.jsp using Ajax.

FYI: host1 is being served by IIS 7 and Apache Tomcat (for JSP pages).  And host2 is using IIS 7 and ASP.

How can I retrieve this page using a Ajax POST request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't with a standard AJAX call due to cross-domain policies, you would have to use JSONP or a form of JSONP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Also, a common "gotcha" is that the cross-domain policies prevent secure to non-secure ajax as well. So a `https://` page cannot request a `http://` page and vice versa/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  Unfortunately, JSONP is not an option for me since I cannot edit the html page from the ASP side. (complicating matters is one host is JSP and the other is ASP).

Answer (score 1):

`YQL` http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/
and
 `JSON-P`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Will these methods work, even though I have no control over the html page on host2.mydomain.com and it was not designed to encode/decode JSONP?

Comment: use `YQL`. It return complete html of the requested page

Comment: Thank you. What about JSONP?  I thought JSONP is only useful if the page being requested is aware that it must encode JSONP.  Is that correct?

Comment: `JSON` or `JSON-P` is used when server return data in `JSON` format. `JSON-P` is used to ByPass the same origin policy.

Answer (score 1):

By setting proper CORS headers if you are using modern browsers. Have a look [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

Answer (score 1):

You are just going across subdomains so can do it using an iframe, look to this question - [A question about cross-domain (subdomain) ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648899/a-question-about-cross-domain-subdomain-ajax-request)

The solution referenced: http://www.tomhoppe.com/index.php/2008/03/cross-sub-domain-javascript-ajax-iframe-etc/

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This would be a great solution if I could modify both pages; however, as I said in the question, I don't have access to the html page.

Comment: Could you just not use ajax and rather include the first page as an iframe on the second page?

Comment: I could but the issue I'm having with that is out of the scope of the question I posed.  Thank you for your suggestion, though.

Answer (score 1):

you write a server-side script to retrieve the page contents, then you use Ajax to request your script

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.  How can this be done, though?  One box is IIS/Tomcat and the other is IIS/ASP.  How can I write a Java/JSP script which will talk to the IIS/ASP box and retrieve it's dynamically created html page.  I would need at least need some sort of web service which hands off requests from each box.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm afraid I can't help you! I am a PHP developer, I have not clue how to do it otherwise

Comment: Yeah, PHP is my forte, as well.  I prefer it.  Thank you though for your help.