# Access Source Code of Sub-Domain

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to access the source of a sub-domain page I control?

For example: 
www.example.com/test.html runs javascript that calls up login.example.com and returns the source of login.example.html

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648899/a-question-about-cross-domain-subdomain-ajax-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where it gets fun using document.domain.

**example.com/test.html page's html**

```
<script>document.domain = "example.com";</script>
<iframe src="subdomain.example.com/domain.html" style="display:none"></iframe>

<script>
  /* make ajax calls or access iframe of the subdomain*/
</script>
```

**HTML for subdomain.example.com/domain.html** [page in iframe]

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <script>document.domain = "example.com";</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, no, it's a security feature on browsers to prevent websites from overusing frames and ajax: it's called the [**Same Origin Policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

But if you own or manage both domains, you can allow them to share resources by using the HTTP headers: Origin & Access-Control-Allow-Origin, or by using the document.domain property in Javascript.